# Trying to add cameraPreviewLayer to swift app

Tags: ios, swift

could someone help me, Im not understanding what im doing wrong,Im trying to preview cameraInout throughout a AvPreviewVideoLayer, but when opening the app it shows me a black background instead of the camera view.
Thanks,
Here is the code:

```
var cameraInput : AVCaptureDeviceInput!
var videoSession : AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

}

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    
    
    //Camera of Device
    guard let videoCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
    else{
        print("Camera Device doesnt work")
        return
    }
    
    //camera into device input
    guard
        let cameraInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCamera),
        videoSession.canAddInput(cameraInput)
        else { return }
    videoSession.addInput(cameraInput)
    
    self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: videoSession)
    

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    
    videoSession.startRunning()
    
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59064305/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi thank you but still don't works